# Making JSON requests at the same time

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I want to get the data from several stock JSON data, but I know how to get only one at a time.
I can't find a way to get several.
It works if I request only AAPPL, but not if I request also FB

More information about the API I'm getting the data from:
https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs#Realtime-Stock-Price

I tried to add more stocks
final String stockID = "AAPL,FB";

In the browser in shows the data
https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/company/price/AAPL,FB?datatype=json
But not in the app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView textView;
ArrayList<String> stocks;//is a resizable array
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; //Returns a view for each object in a collection of data objects you provide
    RequestQueue queue; //Cola peticiones volley

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
       queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); //Creamos una requestqueue para que gestione hilos, peticiones y demas.
        stocks = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stocks); //Pasing the context, the row layout  and the resource?
        textView.setAdapter(adapter); //Setting to the listview the arrayadapter that returns the view from the arraylist
        addstock();

    }
//TODO: add the rest of the stocks
    private void addstock() {
        final String stockID = "AAPL";
        final String stockName = "Apple";






        String url = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/company/price/" +stockID+"?datatype=json";

        //Making the request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try{

                            JSONObject value = response.getJSONObject(stockID);

                            String price = value.getString("price");
                            String Linestock = stockName+ ":"+price+"$";
                            stocks.add(Linestock);//Adding it to the arraylist
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //And to the view
                        } catch (Exception e){

                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO: Handle error

                    }

                });
            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear , at least for me

Comment: Can you update the code to show how you're processing multiple stockIDs please? If you simply set `stockID` to `AAPL,FB` the line `response.getJSONObject(stockID)` won't work, because there's no object by `AAPL,FB` and the null pointer exception will be caught and swallowed by your empty `catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your requests asynchronous.
To do so, you could checkout this [tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html):

I personally use the okhttp3 package.
With this you can build a function like this:

```
public static String performPostCall(String requestURL, JSONObject postDataParams, String auth)
{
    String response;

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Send: " + postDataParams.toString() + " to " + requestURL + " Auth: " + auth);

    try
    {
        Request request;

        Builder tmp = new Builder();

        tmp.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        tmp.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        tmp.writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        OkHttpClient client = tmp.build();

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, postDataParams.toString());

        if (auth.equals(""))
        {
            request = new Request.Builder().url(requestURL).post(body).addHeader("Accept", "application/json").addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").build();
        }
        else
        {
            request = new Request.Builder().url(requestURL).post(body).addHeader("Accept", "application/json").addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").addHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + auth).build();
        }

        Response recv = client.newCall(request).execute();
        response = recv.body().string();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        response = "{\"api_version\":1,\"status\":-1}";

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Received: " + response);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the API mentioned supports passing multiple stock codes, so this can be achieved with a single request.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply set `stockID` to `AAPL,FB` the line

```
response.getJSONObject(stockID)
```

won't work, because there's no object by `AAPL,FB` and the null pointer exception will be caught and swallowed by your empty catch block.

```
 try{

    String[] stockIDs = stockID.Split(","); // assuming stockID is the full string you passed to the API. i.e "AAPL,FB" so we have to get individual stocks.

    for(int i= 0; i < stockIDs.size; i++) { 
        JSONObject value = response.getJSONObject(stockIDs[i]);

        String price = value.getString("price");
        String Linestock = stockName+ ":"+price+"$";
        stocks.add(Linestock);//Adding it to the arraylist
     }
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //And to the view

} catch (Exception e){
  // Log.e(....); so you see the error on LogCat atleast
}
```

You could also iterate the properties of the JSON object regardless of the ones you passed to the API.